# Removing a log from product notation?

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions, logarithms, maximum-likelihood

For example, I'm trying to find the MLE for $\theta$ by taking the log-likelihood of pdf:

$ f(x|\theta)=\frac{(\theta-1)log(x)}{x^\theta} $

$ \log \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{(\theta-1) \log(x)}{x^\theta} $

Is there a way to take the $\log(x)$ out? I don't want to take the logarithm of a logarithm:

$ \log(\theta-1)+ \log \log(x)-\theta\log(x) $

I'm not very good at differentiating, so I'm not sure when I differentiate by $\theta$  if the $\log \log(x)$ would just go away since there's no theta attached?

Comment: Your product doesn't seem to make sense - what does $1=n$ mean as the lower limit on the product? Should it be something like $i=1$? And do you mean to have $\log(x_i)$ instead of $\log(x)$? In any case it looks like you will end up having to take the log of a log.

Comment: I changed the n=1 to i=1, thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to take the log of a log? or when I differentiate by $\theta$ would that just go away?

Comment: Yes, $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} g(x)=0$ for any $g$ which is just a function of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the log-likelihood function is
$$g(\theta) = \log\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(\theta-1)}{x_i^\theta}\log(x_i)\right)=n\log(\theta-1)-\theta\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(x_i)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(\log(x_i)).$$
Observe that you need to take the derivative w.r.t. $\theta$. Consequently,
$$g'(\theta) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(n\log(\theta-1)-\theta\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(x_i)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(\log(x_i))\right)\\=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(n\log(\theta-1)-\theta\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(x_i)\right) + 0,$$
as $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\log(\log(x_i))=0$.

Comment: And thus $$\theta_{MLE}=1+\frac n{\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)}$$